# How to use Angular.js to populate multiple select fields using AJAX calls to different endpoints

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I apologize up front for the possible lack of clarity for this question, but I'm new to Angular.js and my knowledge of it is still slightly hazy. I have done the Angular.js tutorial and googled for answers, but I haven't found any.

I have multiple select/option html elements, not inside a form element, and I'm populating them using AJAX. Each form field is populated by values from a different SharePoint list. I'm wondering if there is a way to implement this using Angular.js?

I would like to consider building this using Angular because I like some of it features such as data-binding, routing, and organizing code by components. But I can't quite grasp how I could implement it in this situation while coding using the DRY principle.

Currently, I have a single AJAX.js file and I have a Javascript file that contains an array of the different endpoints I need to connect to along with specific query parameters. When my page loads, I loop through the arrays and for each element, I call the GET method and pass it the end-point details.

The code then goes on to find the corresponding select element on the page and appends the option element returned by the ajax call.

I'm new to Angular, but from what I understand, I could create a custom component for each select element. I would place the component on the page and all the select and options that are associated with that component would appear there. The examples I've seen demonstrated, associate the ajax call with the code for the component. I'm thinking that I could use a service and have each component dependent on that service and the component would pass it's specific query details to the service's ajax call.

**My current code** - Program flow: main -> data retrieval -> object creation | main -> form build.

Called from index.html - creates the multiple query strings that are passed to ajax calls - ajax calls are once for each query string - the very last function in the file is a call to another function to build the form elements.

```
var snbApp = window.snbApp || {};

snbApp.main = (function () {
    var main = {};
    main.loadCount = 0;

    main.init = function () {

        function buildSelectOptions(){

            //***
            //Build select options from multiple SharePoint lists
            //***
            var listsArray = snbApp.splistarray.getArrayOfListsForObjects();

            for(var i = 0; i < listsArray.length; i++){
                var listItem = listsArray[i];
                var qryStrng =  listItem.list +
        "?$select=" + listItem.codeDigits + "," + listItem.codeDescription + "," + listItem.ItemStatus + "&$orderby=" + listItem.codeDescription + "&$filter="+listItem.ItemStatus+" eq true" + "&$inlinecount=allpages"

                var listDetails = {
                    listName: listItem.list,
                    listObj: listItem,
                    url: "http://myEnv/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listItem.list +
        "?$select=" + listItem.codeDigits + "," + listItem.codeDescription + "," + listItem.ItemStatus + "&$orderby=" + listItem.codeDescription + "&$filter="+listItem.ItemStatus+" eq true" + "&$inlinecount=allpages"
                };
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(snbApp.dataretriever.letsBuild(listDetails), _onQueryFailed);

            }

            //***
            //Build select option from other API endpoint
            //***
            var listDetails = {
                listName:"SNB_SecondaryActivityCodes",
                url: "http://myEnv/requests/odata/v1/Sites?$filter=(IsMajor eq true or IsMinor eq true) and IsActive eq true and IsPending eq false and CodePc ne null and IsSpecialPurpose eq false&$orderby=CodePc"
            };
            snbApp.dataretriever.letsBuild(listDetails);
        }

        buildSelectOptions();

        //***
        //Add delay to populate fields to ensure all data retrieved from AJAX calls
        //***
        var myObj = setTimeout(delayFieldPopulate,5000);

        function delayFieldPopulate(){
            var optObj = snbApp.optionsobj.getAllOptions();
            var osType = $("input[name=os_platform]:checked").val();
            snbApp.formmanager.buildForm(osType, optObj);

        }
    };

    function _onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed.\nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    return main
})();
```

AJAX calls here - called from main/previous file:

```
var snbApp = window.snbApp || {};

snbApp.dataretriever = (function () {
    var listsArray = snbApp.splistarray.getArrayOfListsForObjects();

    function getListData(listItem) {

        var eventType = event.type;
        var baseURL = listItem.url;

        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            }
        })
        .done(function(results){
            snbApp.objectbuilderutility.buildObjectFields(results, listItem);

        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
            //console.log("Error:" + errorThrown + ": " + myListName);
        });
    }

    function _onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed.\nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    return{
        letsBuild:function(item) {
            getListData(item);
        }
    };

})();
```

Builds a item name object - called from recursive AJAX calls / previous file

```
var snbApp = window.snbApp || {};
snbApp.objectbuilderutility = (function () {
    function formatItemCode(itemCode, eventType){
        if(eventType !== 'change'){ //for load event
            var pattern = /^CE/;
            var result = pattern.test(itemCode);
            if(result){
                return itemCode.slice(2);
            }else{
                return itemCode.slice(0,3);
            }
        }else{ //for change event
            var pattern = /^CE/;
            var result = pattern.test(itemCode);
            if(result){
                return itemCode.slice(2);
            }else{
                return itemCode.slice(3);
            }
        }   
    }

    return{
        buildObjectFields: function(returnedObj, listItem){ //results:returnedObj, prevItem:listItem
            //***
            //For SharePoint list data
            //***
            if (listItem.listName !== "SNB_SecondaryActivityCodes") {
                var theList = listItem.listName;
                var firstQueryParam = listItem.listObj.codeDigits;
                var secondQueryParam = listItem.listObj.codeDescription;
                var returnedItems = returnedObj.d.results;
                var bigStringOptions = "";

                //regex to search for SecondaryFunctionCodes in list names
                var pattern = /SecondaryFunctionCodes/;
                var isSecFunction = pattern.test(theList);
                if(isSecFunction){
                    bigStringOptions = "<option value='0' selected>Not Applicable</option>";
                }else{
                    bigStringOptions = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Option</option>";
                }

                $.each(returnedItems, function (index, item) {
                    var first = "";
                    var second = "";
                    for (var key in item) {
                        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            if (key != "__metadata") {
                                if (key == firstQueryParam) {
                                    first = item[key];
                                }
                                if (key == secondQueryParam) {
                                    second = item[key];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    bigStringOptions += "<option value=" + first + " data-code=" + first + ">" + second + "</option>";
                });

                var str = theList.toLowerCase();
                snbApp.optionsobj.updateFunctionOrActivity(theList.toLowerCase(), bigStringOptions);

                //***
                //For other API
                //***
            } else {
                var theList = listItem.listName;
                var bigStringOptions = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Option</option>";
                var returnedItems = returnedObj.value;

                for(var i = 0; i < returnedItems.length; i++){

                    var item = returnedItems[i];

                        //***
                        //change event type means the user selected a field
                        //***
                        if(listItem.eventType === "change"){
                            var siteCodeChange = item.SiteCodePc;
                            if (typeof siteCodeChange === "string" & siteCodeChange != "null") {
                                siteCodeChange = siteCodeChange < 6 ? siteCodeChange : siteCodeChange.slice(3);
                            }

                            bigStringOptions += "<option value='" + item.Id + "' data-code='" + siteCodeChange + "' data-isDivSite='" + item.IsDivisionSite + "' data-isDistSite='" + item.IsDistrictSite + "' data-divID='" + item.DivisionSiteId + "' data-distID='" + item.DistrictSiteId + "'>(" + siteCodeChange + ") " + item.Name + "</option>";

                            snbApp.formmanager.buildSelectSiteLocations(bigStringOptions);

                        //***
                        //load event which means this happens when the page is loaded
                        //***
                        }else{

                            var siteCodeLoad = item.SiteCodePc;
                            if (typeof siteCodeLoad === "string" & siteCodeLoad != "null") {
                                var siteCodeLoad = siteCodeLoad.length < 4 ? siteCodeLoad : siteCodeLoad.slice(0, 3);
                            }

                            bigStringOptions += "<option value='" + item.Id + "' data-code='" + siteCodeLoad + "' data-isDivSite='" + item.IsDivisionSite + "' data-isDistSite='" + item.IsDistrictSite + "' data-divID='" + item.DivisionSiteId + "' data-distID='" + item.DistrictSiteId + "'>(" + siteCodeLoad + ") " + item.Name + "</option>";

                            snbApp.optionsobj.updateFunctionOrActivity(theList.toLowerCase(), bigStringOptions);    
                        }

                }

            }              
        }
    };
})();
```

Form management - called from previous file, gets all select elements on page and appends items from the object in previous file to each select element.

```
var snbApp = window.snbApp || {};

//Direct interface to the form on the page
snbApp.formmanager = (function(){
    var form = {};
    form.content_holder = document.getElementById("content_holder"); 
    form.sec_act_codes = document.getElementById("snb_secondary_activity_codes"); 
    form.prim_func_codes = document.getElementById("snb_primary_function_codes"); 
    form.sec_func_codes = document.getElementById("snb_secondary_function_codes"); 
    form.sec_func_nums = document.getElementById("snb_secondary_function_numbers"); 
    form.host_options = document.getElementById("snb_host_options"); 
    form.site_locs_div = document.getElementById("site_locations_div"); 
    form.site_locs = document.getElementById("snb_site_locations"); 
    form.dc_or_off_prem_div = document.getElementById("dc_or_off_premise_div"); 
    form.dc_off_prem_codes = document.getElementById("snb_dc_offpremise_codes"); 

    var snb_secondary_activity_codes = "";
    var snb_primary_function_codes = "";
    var snb_secondary_function_codes = "";
    var snb_secondary_function_numbers = "";
    var snb_host_options = "";
    var snb_site_locations = "";
    var snb_dc_op = "";


    //builds the server location hosting options selection
    function buildLocationTypeSelector() {
        var locationOptionsString = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Select Option</option>";
        for (var i = 0; i < locationOptions.length; i++) {
            var location = locationOptions[i];
            locationOptionsString += "<option value=" + location.hostLocale + " data-code=" + location.code + ">" + location.hostLocale + "</option>";
        }
        $("#snb_host_options").append(locationOptionsString);
    }

    function buildSiteLocations(bigString){
        if(bigString === undefined){
            var siteLocs = document.getElementById("snb_site_locations");
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");

            newOption.setAttribute("value", 0);
            newOption.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
            newOption.setAttribute("checked","checked");

            var newText = document.createTextNode("Select Option");
            newOption.appendChild(newText);
            siteLocs.appendChild(newOption);
        } else{
            var siteLocs = document.getElementById("snb_site_locations");
            siteLocs.innerHTML = bigString;
        }   
    }



    return {
        form:form,
        buildSelectSiteLocations: function(bigString){
            buildSiteLocations(bigString);
        },
        buildForm: function (osType, optObj) {
          buildLocationTypeSelector();
          buildSecondaryFunctionNumberSelector();
          buildSiteLocations();

          if(osType === 'windows'){
            $("#snb_secondary_activity_codes").append(optObj.windows.secondary_activity);
            $("#snb_primary_function_codes").append(optObj.windows.primary_function);
            $("#snb_secondary_function_codes").append(optObj.windows.secondary_function);
            $("#snb_site_locations").append(optObj.windows.site_location);
            $("#snb_dc_offpremise_codes").append(optObj.windows.dc_offpremise);
          }else{
            $("#snb_secondary_activity_codes").append(optObj.unix.secondary_activity);
            $("#snb_primary_function_codes").append(optObj.unix.primary_function);
            $("#snb_secondary_function_codes").append(optObj.unix.secondary_function);
            $("#snb_site_locations").append(optObj.unix.site_location);
            $("#snb_dc_offpremise_codes").append(optObj.unix.dc_offpremise);
          }
        }
    };
})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance to see your code please? Because it seem that you don't use angularjs correctly by your description (_"The code then goes on to **find** the corresponding **select element** on the page and **appends** the option element returned by the ajax call."_) I believe that you're still thinking the good-old  (or not that good) DOM manipulation, instead of letting angular handle it for you

Comment: Hello Alon. You are correct, my **current** code uses direct DOM manipulation and I'm trying to get away from that by using Angular. I am editing my my initial question to include some of my code.